# Eliminar una carpeta con antiguedad de 7 DÍAS de windows mediante un bash de linux

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell-script

Estoy tratando de eliminar carpetas con antiguedad de 7 Días en windows desde mi servidor linux mediante un script en Bash.

```
#! /bin/bash -x

#definitions

mount -t cifs //XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/des_bk_eva /media/backup/ --o rw,username=NAME SERVER,password=XXXXXXX,domain=YYYYYYYY

#Local directory
bddir_local="/media/backups_bd"

#remote directory
bddir_remote="/media/backup/db/mysql"

#log file
logfile="/home/administrador/logs/backup_evd.log"

#starting timestamp
timestamp=`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`

#backups_bd synchronization
rsync -avz --exclude 'test*' $bddir_local ${bddir_remote}

**find /media/backup/db/mysql/backups_bd/* -type d -ctime +6 -print -exec rm -rf {} \;** 

umount /media/backup
```

el comando `find` es el que estoy utilizando pero esto solo me funciona para linux.

Comment: ¿y si utilizas Git Bash? Permite ejecutar un script de Bash en Windows

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' O WSL, o cygwin, conemu, docker y que monte todo xdd.